# vim: can not match whitespaces after tabs

Tags: vim

I have text like this (1 or 0 tab + multiple whitespaces at line beginning):

```
(tab)   There are a tab and 4 whitespaces before me.    // line 1
(tab)     There are a tab and 6 whitespaces before me.  // line 2
       There are 6 whitespaces before me.               // line 3
   There are 4 whitespaces before me.                   // line 4
```

When i use `^[\t\s]\s*`, only line 1,2 are matched, line 3, 4 are not matched, why?

(When i use `^\s*`, line 3 and 4 can be matched.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is interesting. I'm not sure why the `\s` doesn't work inside of `[]` brackets. Perhaps it is because `[]` defines explicit characters and `\s` is ambiguous (it can stand for multiple characters). In other words `\s` stands for any whitespace, including a tab(`\t`). However, if you explicitly specify a space in this case (`^[\t ]\s*`) it will work.

Comment: Yes, that is what i tried and found out (after 46 times of trying). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you can not use `\s` to match whitespace within `[]`. 
Just use  to match it within `[]`.

Comment: Correct. `\t` is an escape sequence for <Tab> (like `\n`), but `\s` is a special atom. These have to be combined like this: `\(\s\|[\t]\)`

Answer (score 0):

As noted `\s` doesn't work within `[]`, alternatively you could use the `[:blank:]` character class:

```
^[[:blank:]]\+
```